# Ethernet network problem causing /var/log files to fill up all available space

Tags: networking, kernel, ethernet

I've been having a network problem that fills up the files **kern.log** and **syslog** until my SSD doesn't have any space left.

I noticed this problem occurs when I do these steps:

1. Ubuntu is connected to the ethernet.
2. Disconnect the cable, connect
3. After a while, move computer back, disconnect the wireless and reconnect the ethernet cable.
4. Wait a random amount of time (usually hours).
5. Ubuntu automatically disconnects from ethernet (cable still inserted, router working fine).
6. Ubuntu automatically connects to the wireless network.
7. The above mentioned files start to get filled with (almost) the same string:

   Nov 27 10:53:01 computer_name kernel: [148131.895532] alx 0000:08:00.0 enp8s0: fatal interrupt 0x4019607, resetting

Since Ubuntu connects to the wireless, sometimes I don't detect the error and continue browsing/working. One or two days later my SSD has 0 bytes left, sometimes even breaking Ubuntu to the point I can't login and I have to boot into the terminal mode to remove the log files.

Some information that might be useful:

**lsb_release -a**

```
Code:
No LSB modules are available.Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:    yakkety
```

**uname -a**

```
Code:
Linux <computer_name> 4.8.0-27-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 20 21:03:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**lspci -v (for my ethernet controller)**

```
Code:
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at d2400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [c0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/16 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d8] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [180] Device Serial Number ff-34-89-1a-ec-f4-bb-ff
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
```

Comment: Googling the error shows that it is a well-known and not yet solved bug. If you have wireless available, I'd blacklist the driver *alx* and not use it at all. If that is a workable solution, I'll propose it as an answer.

Comment: I can't rely on the wireless connection for the amount of data I work with. Are you talking about the expired bug in ubuntu's launchpad? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1264125

Comment: Yes, indeed, as well as this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1330844 and this: https://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-bugs/2016-06/msg00065.html and many more. If wireless is not a viable option, my next suggestion is to replace the card. Sorry.